# Bounding the increments of $\sin(e^{-x})$

Tags: calculus, inequality

Show that $|\sin(e^{-b}) -\sin(e^{-a})| \leq {b-a \over e^{-a}}$ 
for all $a \leq b$

This is part of a basic calculus class so i would appreciate answers suitable for my knowledge.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let $f(x) = \sin(e^{-x})$. Then $f'(x) = -e^{-x} \cos(e^{-x})$. Invoke the mean-value theorem: if $a < b$ there exists a point $c \in (a,b)$ so that
$$ |f(b) - f(a)| = |f'(c)| |b-a|.$$ Thus $$|\sin(e^{-b}) - \sin(e^{-a})| = |-e^{-c} \cos(e^{-c})||b-a| \le e^{-c}(b-a) \le e^{-a}(b-a)$$
because $a < c$ implies $e^{-c} \le e^{-a}$.

The inequality is obvious if $a = b$.

Comment: Magnificent. such simplicity...